# Django form does not save foreign key

Tags: python, django, methods, save, modelform

I'm trying to do a simple commenting app that composed of a title and comments under that title. I can create title and I can see the form for adding comment entries to this title. I type and click submit and it does nothing. When I use admin panel, I can add entries without a problem.

This is my models:

```
class Baslik(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.title)


    def get_absolute_url(self, ):
        return reverse('baslik', args=[self.slug])


class Entry(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    baslik = models.ForeignKey(Baslik, null=True, blank=True)
    icerik = models.TextField(max_length=50000)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.icerik)
```

this is my views' entry part:

```
def tek(request, slug):
    baslik = Baslik.objects.get(slug=slug)
    entryler = baslik.entry_set.all()
    form2 = EntryForm(request.POST or None)
    if form2.is_valid():
        entry = form2.save(commit=False)
        entry.user = request.user
        entry.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/baslik/%s'%(baslik.slug))


    return render_to_response("baslik/tek.html", locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

this is my forms.py:

```
class BaslikForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Baslik
        fields = ('title',)

class EntryForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        fields = ('icerik',)
```

this is my admin.py:

```
class EntryInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Entry


class BaslikAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('__unicode__','live_link')
    search_fields = ['title']
    list_filter = ['timestamp', 'updated']
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ('title',)}

    readonly_fields = ['live_link', 'timestamp', 'updated']
    inlines = [EntryInline]
    class Meta:
        model = Baslik


    def live_link(self,obj):
        link = "<a href='/baslik/" + str(obj.slug)+ "/'>" + obj.title + "<a/>"
        return link

    live_link.allow_tags = True

admin.site.register(Baslik, BaslikAdmin)
```

What should I do to solve this? Please be explanatory. I'm very new at Django.
Thanks.

Comment: First of all. check for `POST` -> `if request.method == "POST":` and then do `form2 = EntryForm(request.POST)`

Comment: I did what you say but now it doesn't even show enter comment form.

Comment: Not sure to understand what you want to do, but if the missing foreign key is the baslik one in Entry, it's because you need to add it in your EntryForm. To do it you can do 

`fields = ('icerik', 'baslik' )`

Comment: I have a title(baslik) and I want to add comments to it(entry). I already created a title(baslik) but I cannot add comments(entry) to it because my form does not save it. If it saves I will have a page that composed of a title(baslik) and comments(entries). This is the summery of project. :)

Comment: Ok understood. So as I said before, you need to add the baslik field in your EntryForm to link the comment to the baslik .

Then check the value of `request.POST` and `form2.is_valid()` (by doing a print for exemple)

Comment: Yes, that is because you are not sending `form = EntryForm()` from outside of `POST`

Comment: Ok, it worked but I don't want to select a baslik in form when I add comment to it. How can I solve it?

Comment: You have to do it the same way you do for user, after `form2.save(commit=False)` add `entry.baslik = baslik`

Comment: I also needed to customize form template but it worked. Thanks a lot!